# Understanding logic behind Integer.highestOneBit() method implementation

Tags: java, bit

Java Integer class has the static method highestOneBit method which will return a value with a single one-bit, in the position of the highest-order one-bit in the specified value, or zero if the specified value is itself equal to zero.

For example input of int 17 will return 16; As 17 can be represented in binary as 10001 so it will return the furthest bit left which is equal to 16.

And in Integer class it has the following implementation in Java doc.

```
    public static int highestOneBit(int i) {
    // HD, Figure 3-1
    i |= (i >>  1);
    i |= (i >>  2);
    i |= (i >>  4);
    i |= (i >>  8);
    i |= (i >> 16);
    return i - (i >>> 1);
}
```

I just want to know the logic behind implementing it this way and the logic behind using shift operations
. Can any one put some light on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This algorithm calculates for a given `i` whose binary representation is:

```
0..01XXXXXXX...XXXX
```

the value

```
0..011111111...1111
```

That's what the 5 `|=` operators do.

Then, in the return statement, it subtracts from it that value shifted right by one bit

```
0..001111111...1111
```

to get the result

```
0..010000000...0000
```

How does it work:

The highest possible 1 bit the the 32nd (left most) bit. Suppose the input number has 1 in that bit:

```
1XXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX
```

You or that value with the value shifted right by 1 `(i >>  1)` and get

```
11XXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX
```

Then you or that new value with the value shifted right by 2 `(i >>  2)` and get

```
1111XXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX
```

Then you or that new value with the value shifted right by 4 `(i >>  4)` and get

```
11111111 XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX
```

Then you or that new value with the value shifted right by 8 `(i >>  8)` and get

```
11111111 11111111 XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX
```

Finally you or that new value with the value shifted right by 16 `(i >>  16)` and get

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

If the highest 1 bit is smaller than the 32nd bit, these operations still turn all the bits to the right of it to 1 and keep the remaining (higher bits) 0.

Comment: can you please link you answer with code and which portion is doing what .. ?               
 i |= (i >>  1);   and this goes to 16 and in return statement   return i - (i >>> 1);  i am not being able to connect the dots.

Answer (score 2):

The `i |=` statements help to compute a sequence of ones that is the same length as `i`. For example, for `101011` it computes `111111`. I've explained how it works in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46268833/explanation-for-computing-the-nearest-power-of-two-greater-than-the-argument-usi/46269026#46269026) (I can't retype it right now since I am on mobile).

So basically, once you have the string of ones, subtracting itself shifted right one bit gives the H.O. bit.

```
111111 - (111111 >>> 1) = 111111 - 011111 = 100000
```

Answer (score 2):

The first five lines (`i |= (i >> x)`) will set every bit below the highest 1-bit to 1. Then, the final line will subtract every 1-bit below the highest one, so that only the highest 1-bit will remain.

For simplicity, let's pretend an `int` was 8 bits. The code would in that case be like this:

```
public static int highestOneBit(int i) {
    i |= (i >>  1);
    i |= (i >>  2);
    i |= (i >>  4);
    return i - (i >>> 1);
}
```

Now, let's say we have the value 128 (`10000000`). This is what would happen:

```
// i == 10000000
i |= (i >>  1); // i = 10000000 | 11000000 = 11000000 
i |= (i >>  2); // i = 11000000 | 11110000 = 11110000 
i |= (i >>  4); // i = 11110000 | 11111111 = 11111111
return i - (i >>> 1); // 11111111 - 01111111 = 10000000
```

The `>>` is an arithmetic right shift, so it will preserve the signed bit.
The last `>>>` is a logical right shift, which will not preserve the signed bit. It will always insert zeroes on the left side.

Now, let's try with 64 (01000000):

```
// i == 01000000
i |= (i >>  1); // i = 01000000 | 00100000 = 01100000 
i |= (i >>  2); // i = 01100000 | 00011000 = 01111000 
i |= (i >>  4); // i = 01111000 | 00000111 = 01111111
return i - (i >>> 1); // 01111111 - 00111111 = 01000000
```